# xamarin forms - how to tidy up layout - to the bottom right of a listView

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin.forms, label

the following code shows the following image:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin"
             x:Class="TestProjectXamarin.Views.ShoppingCart">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ShoppingCartList}" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="None">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid Padding="10" RowSpacing="10" ColumnSpacing="10">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Id}" VerticalOptions="End" IsVisible="False"/>
                                <controls:CircleImage  Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="1" HeightRequest="60" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFill" WidthRequest="66" Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalOptions="End"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="{Binding Detail}"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat='£{0}'}"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="{Binding Quantity}"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="{Binding SubTotalForItem, StringFormat='£{0}'}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
           <Label x:Name="TotalForItems" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" Margin="20,20" FontSize="Large"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

[image]

I would like the total at the bottom moved to directly below the last subtotal of £50, so there is no gap, i have tried `VerticalTextAlignment="Start"` but to no avail

Thanks

Comment: use a Footer instead

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should never ever put a `ListView` in `StackLayout`. You are just asking for more trouble in terms of layout cycles and redraw timings.

As @Jason has mentioned, you can solve the current problem with ListView's `Footer`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin"
             x:Class="TestProjectXamarin.Views.ShoppingCart">
    <ContentPage.Content>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ShoppingCartList}" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="None">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid Padding="10" RowSpacing="10" ColumnSpacing="10">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Id}" VerticalOptions="End" IsVisible="False"/>
                                <controls:CircleImage  Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="1" HeightRequest="60" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFill" WidthRequest="66" Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalOptions="End"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="{Binding Detail}"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat='£{0}'}"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="{Binding Quantity}"/>
                                <Label Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="{Binding SubTotalForItem, StringFormat='£{0}'}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <ListView.Footer>
                    <Label x:Name="TotalForItems" HorizontalAlignment="End" FontSize="Large"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                </ListView.Footer>
            </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Also don't use `TextAlignment` properties unless absolutely necessary!